# Returned jquery from ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i have 2 radio buttons that are supposed to change a line in the page.

the code for the line to be changed is:

```
<span id='checkout_total' class="pricedisplay checkout-total">
<span class='pricedisplay'>&#036;13.00</span></span>
```

When clicking the radio buttons i have an ajax request that returns this:

```
jQuery('.pricedisplay.checkout-total').html("<span class='pricedisplay'>&#036;16.00</span>");
```

So now the span class='pricedisplay' should show 16.00 instead of 13.00

problem is, its not changing in the page..still shows 13.00.

if i use the dev tools in chrome and paste the jquery line in the console it changes correctly

Comment: `.pricedisplay .checkout-total` space have meaning!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it (for a lighter code)

```
jQuery('#checkout_total .pricedisplay').html("&#036;16.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

your selector should either be `#checkout_total` or `.checkout_total`..cannot use `.pricedisplay` because both the spans has the same class and you are replacing the `span` element inside `<span id='checkout_total' class="pricedisplay checkout-total">`

```
 $(function(){  //just incase if you missed this
    jQuery('#checkout_total').html("<span class='pricedisplay'>&#036;16.00</span>");
 });
```

since you have an id mentioned in that  element.. i would go with `jQuery('#checkout_total')`.

if you just have to change the text inside span then you can use

```
jQuery('#checkout_total .pricedisplay').text("&#036;16.00");
```

Comment: it should... make sure you are calling this inside a document.ready function...and you post your code or create a fiddle